# Is there a service call for getting the total inertia of a robot in Gazebo

Tags: gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I am working with gazebo and I have a model of a robot. I would like to know its total inertia. The robot is made by fixed link only so the inertia should always be the same. I tried looking for some kind of rosservice (like /gazebo/get_model_state) but couldn't find anything.
thanks for your help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11125/is-there-a-service-call-for-getting-the-total-inertia-of-a-robot-in-gazebo/) by [erpa](https://answers.ros.org/users/995/erpa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 111 on 2011-09-06

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) on 2011-09-06**:
none exist now, but a patch to get total inertia will be great!  can you create a feature request on trac (https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/newticket)?  thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From @hsu: None exist now.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-11-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0